# Is it possible to solve something like this? $p\cdot(ax+d)^{2.4}+q\cdot(bx+d)^{2.4}+r\cdot(cx+d)^{2.4}=s$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find $x \ge 0$ such that
>   $$
>   0.2126\left(\frac{1.4x + 0.055}{1.055}\right)^{2.4}
> + 0.7152\left(\frac{\frac{13}{15}x + 0.055}{1.055}\right)^{2.4}
> + 0.0722\left(\frac{0.6x + 0.055}{1.055}\right)^{2.4} \\ = 0.175
> $$

I want to calculate color from relative luminance using
https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG/#dfn-relative-luminance

Comment: It seems you need numerical methods, like the  Newton–Raphson method, to solve this equation.

Comment: @callculus thank you, I'll read something like Newton–Raphson method for dummies.

Comment: Depending on how accurate an answer you require, you may not need any particular method here...just do a simple binary search.  $x\approx .065$ is pretty close already.

Comment: You´re welcome. If you have still any questions, after looking at the method, leave a comment.

Comment: @lulu I thought about this, 16 bits should be more than enough, thanks.

Comment: Well, I'd have thought a binary search was the way to go.   The function is very easy to compute after all. Anyway, I'd start there.  If it is too slow, then you could consider more sophisticated techniques.  With $x=.064985$ I get $f(x)=.175009$, for instance.

Comment: @lulu I calculated it using Newton–Raphson method, got 45.63910158648187.
Contrast ratio should be `4.5` with `hue == 20`, `saturation == 40%`, `lightness == x`; `x == 45.63910158648187%`, now i would make universal algorithm.

Comment: That number is obviously wrong.  The first term alone evaluated at that number yields something much larger than $.175$

Comment: @lulu Excuse me, I loose dot in 1.4 :(

Comment: @lulu here is result https://contrast-ratio.com/#hsl%2820%2C40%25%2C45.63910158648187%25%29-on-%23000

Comment: Not sure what that site is doing.  All I am using is the equation you provided.  If that equation is incorrect, then of course my calculation won't give you what you want.

Comment: @lulu It's my fault.

Answer (score 0):

A few points.

(1) It is usually a good idea to get a general idea of what the lhs looks like by plotting it for a range that includes the likely answer. In this case the function is strictly increasing for positive $x$, so that is easy.

(2) In a case like this you can get a reasonable approximation by simple binary search, or by reducing your plotting range. Eg I got this after a few iterations:

[image]

(3) For more accurate work you can use something like the Newton-Raphson approx.

(4) However, I doubt your input data is that accurate. Even if all your data is good to 1 part in $10^4$, I doubt it is worth going for more accuracy than x=0.064985